# Can I embed a silverlight sketchflow player in my web page?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, sketchflow

Hi I'm new to silverlight and sketchflow.  I'm getting on great with creating prototypes and can export to Word etc.

I would really like to embed a prototype in another web page - is this possible and how would I go about it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.  The Silverlight SketchFlow player is a Silverlight application just like any other. 
Here is an msdn page about it:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838145%28VS.95%29.aspx

I also believe Expression Web has the ability to embed a SL project into a webpage for you if you aren't comfortable with html.

Also, 1 more option to explore is the package item on the file menu.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy.

1. Create you sketch flow app in Expression Blend.
2. In Visual Studio add an empty ASP.Net Website to the solution
3. In the properties of the ASP.Net Website, find the Silverlight tab. There you press Add and when happy with all the default settings, press add again.

You are good to go. You can host the Sketch Flow Player online, for you audience to start giving you the feedback ;)